# Opennebula Vm creation failed

Tags: opennebula

I am trying to set up opennebula cloud for experiment purpose on vms created on the top of another opennebula cloud so that base cloud remain undisturb. When I am trying to created vms it is showing the following errors..

Fri Apr 15 18:39:02 2016 [DiM][I]: New VM state is ACTIVE.

Fri Apr 15 18:39:02 2016 [LCM][I]: New VM state is PROLOG.

Fri Apr 15 18:39:25 2016 [LCM][I]: New VM state is BOOT

Fri Apr 15 18:39:25 2016 [VMM][I]: Generating deployment file: /var/lib/one/vms/3/deployment.0

Fri Apr 15 18:39:25 2016 [VMM][I]: ExitCode: 0

Fri Apr 15 18:39:25 2016 [VMM][I]: Successfully execute network driver operation: pre.

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][I]: Command execution fail: cat << EOT | /var/tmp/one/vmm/kvm/deploy '/var/lib/one//datastores/0/3/deployment.0' '192.168.111.122' 3 192.168.111.122

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][I]: error: Failed to create domain from /var/lib/one//datastores/0/3/deployment.0

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][I]: error: Connection is closed

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][E]: Could not create domain from /var/lib/one//datastores/0/3/deployment.0

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][I]: ExitCode: 255

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][I]: Failed to execute virtualization driver operation: deploy.

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [VMM][E]: Error deploying virtual machine: Could not create domain from /var/lib/one//datastores/0/3/deployment.0

Fri Apr 15 18:39:26 2016 [DiM][I]: New VM state is FAILED

Please help me to understand whats wrong I am doing.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help..